# What does this not work in PHP $a= explode(' ', $loadFunction)[0];

Tags: php

I am trying to access an array without using another varibale.

For example

```
$loadFunction = "a b c d";

$a= explode(' ', $loadFunction)[0];
```

I get Parser error in PHP 5.3.3

any way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array dereferencing doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544853/array-dereferencing-doesnt-work)

Comment: [In PHP 5.4] Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0]. http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 7):

This syntax is [acceptable in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), but not lower.

Comment: really? seems so basic...

Comment: Remember this is PHP we're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Closest without PHP 5.4 you're gonna get is,

```
$loadFunction = "a b c d";

list($a) = explode(' ', $loadFunction);
// $a = a
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$loadFunction = "a b c d";
$a = reset(explode(' ', $loadFunction));
// $a = 'a'
```